# Particles restarting throughout rendered animation

Tags: animation, particles, compositing-nodes, emission

I have a short animation which uses a particle emitter to replicate fire.
If i play the animation through the viewport, all seems fine, and the particles continues until it dissipates.

However, in the rendered animation, the particles seems to stutter, with some emitted blocks completely disappearing and reappearing in the next frame, or the particles restarting altogether. I'm using compositing effects to get a pixel-art effect, so I've attached my node setup below. I'm rendering the animation from frames 35 to 200, for context.

[image]
[image: Nodes]

Here is an Imgur link to the animation itself, displaying the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahj6I.jpg

I appreciate any help here, as i'm completely stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I was able to fix this issue by baking the cache of my particle emitter, and rendering from there.